# How can I say whether $g \in \bar {\mathcal M}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R))^+$ such that $\int g \ d(\lambda) < \infty$ and $|f_n| \le g$ exist?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n(x)=\frac n 2 \cos(x)1_{[\frac {-1} n, \frac 1 n]}(x)$ be a function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

I've shown that $f_n \in \mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ and $\int f_n \ d(\lambda) = n \sin(1/n)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \ d(\lambda) = 0$.

How can I say whether $g \in \bar {\mathcal M}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R))^+$ such that $\int g \ d(\lambda) < \infty$ and $|f_n| \le g$ exist ?

I see that $g(0) = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since

$$|\cos(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2};$$

for $|x|$ sufficiently small, we have

$$|f_n(x)| \geq \frac{n}{4} \cdot 1_{\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} \right]}(x).$$

Conclude that

$$|f_n(x)| \geq \frac{C}{|x|} \qquad \text{for all}\, \frac{1}{n+1}<|x| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

for some constant $C>0$ (which does not depend on $n$). Consequently, any function $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g$ has to satisfy

$$|g(x)| \geq \frac{C}{|x|}.$$

What does this mean for the integrability of $g$?